# Inserir componente sem utilizar o método 'setBounds'

Tags: java, swing, combobox

Estou a utilizar um free design no meu projeto e arrastar para o meu jFrame os componentes que quero. No entanto, precisei de utilizar um jComboBox com autocomplete e guiei-me por [este](http://www.algosome.com/articles/java-jcombobox-autocomplete.html) site. Agora queria utilizar a class  'AutocompleteJComboBox' e aplicá-la a uma jCombobox que eu arrastei para a minha frame. Isto é possível?

Já tentei colocar esta parte do código no construtor:

```
List<String> myWords = new ArrayList<>();
        myWords.add("bike");
        myWords.add("car");
        myWords.add("cap");
        myWords.add("cape");
        myWords.add("canadian");
        myWords.add("caprecious");
        myWords.add("catepult");

        StringSearchable searchable = new StringSearchable(myWords);
        AutocompleteJComboBox combo = new AutocompleteJComboBox(searchable);
        //combo.setBounds(600, 200, 100, 25);
        jPanel3.add(combo);
```

A questão é que eu não queria estar a utilizar o método setBounds porque é complicado estar à procura da melhor posição e tamanho para a jComboBox. Caso não utilize esse método, a combo não me aparece no meu jPanel que quero.

Alguma sugestão de como aplicar esse autocomplete a uma jComboBox que arrastei para o meu jFrame?

Comment: Poderia mostrar a criação e inicialização do seu jPanel3?

Comment: A questão é essa, eu não inicializei nada, eu só criei novo jForm e estou a arrastar os componentes no design

Comment: Certo, certo. Mas mostre mais do seu código, principalmente tudo que envolve a variável `jPanel3`.

Comment: Não estou a usar o jPanel3 em lado nenhum do código :s Só tentei mesmo nesse caso para o adicionar mas não funcionou :s

Comment: A solução do seu problema (provavelmente) se resume em uma coisa: a escolha adequada de um [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Mas pra ser bem sincero, acho que não entendi muito bem o seu problema. Você sabe usar bem os LMs? Sabe qual está usando? Sua dúvida é `Como adicionar uma JComboBox em um JPanel sem usar o setBounds()?` ?

Comment: Nunca trabalhei muito com o swing do netbeans, e não estou muito por dentro dos LayoutManagers. Mas resumindo sim, eu quero colocar uma JComboBox no meu jPanel3 sem ser por setBounds

Answer (score 2):

Para adicionar um JComboBox sem ter que definir os *bounds* basta você utilizar um [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) que não exija que eles sejam definidos.

Um Layout Manager moderno e flexível é o [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), ele gera pouco código tornando possível que você faça os ajustes direto na sua classe ao invés de depender do editor gráfico (apesar de que a princípio é melhor você depender sim do editor gráfico, até conhecer melhor as opções que esse LM te oferece).

Um exemplo de um JComboBox do tipo AutocompleteJComboBox dentro de um MigLayout:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Principal extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Principal frame = new Principal();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public Principal() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[424px,grow]", "[40px]"));

        List<String> myWords = new ArrayList<>();
        myWords.add("bike");
        myWords.add("car");
        myWords.add("cap");
        myWords.add("cape");
        myWords.add("canadian");
        myWords.add("caprecious");
        myWords.add("catepult");

        StringSearchable searchable = new StringSearchable(myWords);
        AutocompleteJComboBox combo = new AutocompleteJComboBox(searchable);
        contentPane.add(combo, "cell 0 0,growx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas eu com a class AutoCompleteJComboBox importada no meu projeto, não consigo em vez de adicionar uma combo ao meu jPanel, aplicar a ação do autocomplete a uma jComboBox que eu arrastei para o meu design ?

Comment: @HugoMachado sim, mas você deve mudar a forma de instanciação do objeto. A variável de referência ainda pode ser uma JComboBox, mas o objeto deve ser um AutocompleteJComboBox. Exemplo: `JComboBox<String> combo = new AutocompleteJComboBox(searchable);`. É isso que quer?

Comment: Imaginemos que eu arrastei para o meu design uma combobox e a pus como editável e chama-se 'comboAutocomplete'. É válido eu no meu construtor fazer: comboAutoComplete = new AutocompleteJComboBox(searchable); ?

Comment: @HugoMachado Sim! Desde que seu combo seja do tipo `JComboBox<String>`, para isso basta você mudar manualmente na sua classe.

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância mas estou aqui para aprender :) É possível eu mudar o tipo de Combobox que arrastei para o meu frame neste caso para uma Combobox<String> ? se sim onde faço isso ?

Comment: @HugoMachado Sim, é possível. Quando você arrastar sua combobox para a sua aplicação, um código será criado em sua classe, referente ao elemento que tiver arrastado. Mas ele geralmente cria o código `JComboBox`, e você deve adicionar o `<String>` no código para ficar `JComboBox<String>`. Além disso, você deve trocar tudo que estiver depois do `=` (provavelmente estará `new JComboBox()`), para o código que eu pus acima: `new AutocompleteJComboBox(searchable)`.

Comment: àhh penso que já entendi. Eu vou tentar assim, obrigado pela ajuda :)